# 2560 X 1440@60Hz resolution in Ubuntu 17.10 and Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: drivers

I have a Thin client that uses Intel Pentium N3710 processor. The OS I'm using is Ubuntu 17.10 and Ubuntu 18.04. When I set the resolution to 2560 X 1440, the screen turns blank. I know the monitor does support this resolution, but I'm not able to get this resolution work correctly on the two Ubuntu releases. Has anybody hear this issue before? Does the two Ubuntu release not supporting this resolution? Is there a Kernel driver that can address this issue?

Comment: Does the graphic card in the thin client support that resolution ?

Comment: Yes the graphic card in the thin client does support this resoluiton at this refresh rate.   In Windows 10, I can display this resolution at this refresh rate with no issue at all.

Comment: Have you tried other Hz? If the Hz are incorrect it can cause this issue.